# Разбить список на пары python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Не могу разбить список `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` на все возможные  пары.
Где `[0,1,2]`, `[3,4,5]`, `[6,7,8]`, `[9,10,11]` - Представляют разные группы. То есть всего групп у нас 4.

Нужно разбить так, чтобы в каждой паре были представители из разных групп.
А так же если например существует пара между первой и второй группой, то больше пар между этими группами быть не может.

Получилось разбить только на все возможные пары. Без этих условий

```py
def all_pairs(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        yield []
        return
    if len(lst) % 2 == 1:
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for result in all_pairs(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]):
                yield result
    else:
        a = lst[0]
        for i in range(1,len(lst)):
            pair = (a,lst[i])
            for rest in all_pairs(lst[1:i]+lst[i+1:]):
                yield [pair] + rest
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Какой должен быть результат для приведенных данных?

Comment: потому что это задание надо читать задом наперед. на пары надо разбирать группы, а не список

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

Разобьём на группы

```
n = len(lst) // 4
grps = (lst[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n))

# list(grps) == [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Комбинируем сами группы, а не список

```
from itertools import combinations
cmb = combinations(grps, 2)

# list(cmb) == [([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]), ([0, 1, 2], [6, 7, 8]),
# ([0, 1, 2], [9, 10, 11]), ([3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]), ([3, 4, 5],
# [9, 10, 11]), ([6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11])]
```

Дергаем из каждой пары групп по элементу.

```
result = []
for a,b in cmb:
    result.append((a.pop(),b.pop()))

# result == [(2, 5), (1, 8), (0, 11), (4, 7), (3, 10), (6, 9)]
```

На генераторах:

```
from itertools import combinations

def all_pairs(lst):
    n = len(lst) // 4
    grps = (lst[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n))
    cmb = combinations(grps, 2)
    for a,b in cmb:
        yield ((a.pop(),b.pop()))
```